# How to send email by using MailKit?

Tags: c#, gmail, mailkit

According to the new google politics https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2014/04/new-security-measures-will-affect-older.html I can't sent an email. "Less secure apps" are considered for google the application which don't use OAuth 2.0.

I would like to use MailKit to solve this problem

```
var message = new MimeMessage();

message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Joey Tribbiani", "noreply@localhost.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Mrs. Chanandler Bong", "mymail@gmail.com"));
message.Subject = "How you doin'?";
message.Body = new TextPart("plain"){ Text = @"Hey" };

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
   client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

   ////Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
   client.Authenticate("mymail@gmail.com", "mypassword");

   client.Send(message);
   client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

But I have got `An exception of type 'MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException' occurred in MailKit.dll but was not handled in user code.Additional information: Authentication failed.`

I don't want to change my security settings. Because I want that everything will be secure. That's why I start to use MailKit rather than System.Net.Mail

How can I fix it?

Comment: This isn't about mailkit or C#, it's about Google. Either you have the wrong password or you need to change the security settings of the account [as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231033/using-smtpclient-to-send-an-email-from-gmail)

Comment: I believe this is because you need to setup the connection wiht Oauth 2.0 https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/df7b0f5b9522ed355aa49cfbe56892031d65047f/FAQ.md#how-can-i-log-in-to-a-gmail-account-using-oauth-20

Comment: Actually, there are multiple reasons that GMail can return an authentication error even if the password appears correct - one time passwords, two-factor authentication [as described here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6009563)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is follow [Google's instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) for obtaining OAuth 2.0 credentials for your application.

Once you've done that, the easiest way to obtain an access token is to use Google's [Google.Apis.Auth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/) library:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2 (@"C:\path\to\certificate.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential (new ServiceAccountCredential
    .Initializer ("your-developer-id@developer.gserviceaccount.com") {
    // Note: other scopes can be found here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes
    Scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" },
    User = "username@gmail.com"
}.FromCertificate (certificate));

//You can also use FromPrivateKey(privateKey) where privateKey
// is the value of the field 'private_key' in your serviceName.json file

bool result = await credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync (cancel.Token);

// Note: result will be true if the access token was received successfully
```

Now that you have an access token (`credential.Token.AccessToken`), you can use it with MailKit as if it were the password:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
   client.Connect ("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

   // use the OAuth2.0 access token obtained above
   var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2 ("mymail@gmail.com", credential.Token.AccessToken);
   client.Authenticate (oauth2);

   client.Send (message);
   client.Disconnect (true);
}
```

**Update:**

The above solution is for what Google refers to as "Service Accounts" that are used for server-to-server communication, but if you want OAuth2 support for standard Phone or Desktop apps, for example, you'll need to follow the directions I've written here: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/GMailOAuth2.md

Comment: Will I can sent mail to "no gmail" account?

Comment: You can't use Google's OAuth2 tokens with non-GMail servers. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: What should I do to sent an email for example to `no_gmail@yandex.ru`?

Comment: Use a regular user name and password.

Comment: If I use System.Net.Mail but with X509Certificate2 will I have problem with a new google secure politics?

Comment: Yes. System.Net.Mail does not support the OAuth2 authentication mechanism.

Comment: Where I can find `cancel` variable? And what to do if result equals false?

Comment: it's a `System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - just create one, or pass `CancellationToken.None` instead of `cancel.Token`.

Comment: I went through a lot trying to get this to work, and it turned out because I have a separate domain myemail@mywebsite.com that is managed by gmail I had to go through specials steps listed here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#delegatingauthority

Comment: I got the following execption on RequestAccessTokenAsync 
 method.TokenResponseException: Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.",

Comment: SmtpClient obsolete in NET 4.7 ? https://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.com.es/2017/04/achievement-unlocked-mimekit-and.html#gpluscomments

Comment: @Kiquenet : this SmtpClient is in the Mailkit.Net.Smtp namespace. It is not the same as System.Net.Mail's SmtpClient.

Comment: what is ***Messagge** ? save in drafts ?

Comment: hi @jstedfast I use MailKit, but even everything setup correct, I still have Authentication failed. could you please help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708820/mailkit-authentication-failed

Comment: I know this is a very old post but it's the one that got me closest to make this thing work.
I'm also getting the message "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method". I think I might have to give access to the "https://mail.google.com/" scope to the user in the line' User = "username@gmail.com"', but I haven't found a way to do it yet.
Does anyone have an idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 28):

Tested following code and works for me:

```
        // STEP 1: Navigate to this page https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps & set to "Turn On"

        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Joey Tribbiani", "YOU_FROM_ADDRESS@gmail.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Mrs. Chanandler Bong", "YOU_TO_ADDRESS@gmail.com"));
        message.Subject = "How you doin'?";

        message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = @"Hey Chandler,I just wanted to let you know that Monica and I were going to go play some paintball, you in?-- Joey"
        };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);


            // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
            // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

            // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
            client.Authenticate("YOUR_GMAIL_NAME", "YOUR_PASSWORD");

            client.Send(message);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
```

Comment: I have tried this and I still get a certificate error, is there anyone else that has had this issue?

Comment: Works great with me. Perfect for a student project !
Don't you guys forget this to visit this link before trying out this code! : https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: So anyone who hacks your program will see your Google mail password? Doesn't seem like a good idea to me!

Comment: Works on me. I used in it my test application - using my test gmail account.
In production, I used my client email's smtp server. so no problem with other programmer (or worst hacker) seeing my "App password" - this is just a gmail test account and I can revoke this App password anytime.